# How to add DKIM header on emails sent by ruby on rails using SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, dkim

I have a Ruby on Rails application than sends emails.

Recently my users started complaining than they didn't recieved their emails. They vanished, they didn't even reached spam folder.

I solved some problems related to SPF, but I found out than the emails sent by my application didn't include a DKIM signature header. I thought it was injected by the SMTP server

I am using a third-party email provider (https://mxroute.com/) and my Ruby on Rails connect to its SMTP server.

If I have no access to their DKIM private key. How can I add the corresponding DKIM signature header?

Comment: Where are you hosting the app -- you should be able to add a DKIM record to your domain, create a key and set in mxroute. Mxroute has a number of walk-throughs depending on how you are hosting the site. https://mxroute.com/?s=DKIM

Comment: I have the DKIM record set on my domain, that is not the problem. The problem is that DKIM-Signature header is not set in the email sent by my app. If I use mxrouting webmail the DKIM doesn't have any problem